# Unable to access glassfish served content when using localhost

Tags: glassfish

I created this simple dynamic web project (glassfish 4.1.1 latest atm) using eclipse java ee Mars.2 that I installed 2 days ago.

Checking on the admin, the app is deployed and running fine. I could not access the web app using the `localhost:8080` url but it works when I use `<computername>:8080`.

I could access the admin using localhost:4848.

I tried disabling the firewall but the problem persists.  What could be the problem?

The error is:

```
404 Not Found

No context found for request
```

In eclipse I see the log int he console that says: `Automatic timeout occurred`

Comment: How your listener is configured? See Configuration -> needed configuration -> Network Config -> Network Listeners. And what do you see in logs?

Comment: In the log: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080, I find that odd, I changed it to either localhost/127.0.0.1 in the config page you pointed out, restarted the server and it works now, thank you very much ars

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in comments, you can configure listeners in Configuration -> needed configuration -> Network Config -> Network Listeners. However, it is still rather strange that your localhost doesn't work with `0.0.0.0` IP address, since it is a special address which means "listen on all available IPs on given port". Perhaps your network is somehow misconfigured.